# Вывод фразы, соответствующей диапазону, к которому принадлежит значение

Tags: excel

Суть задачи:

Есть диапазон времени (Ячейка `A1`):

```
 9:00 - 12:00
12:01 - 16:00
```

Есть фраза для диапазона (Ячейка `B1`)

- Для `9:00 - 12:00` - `"Прием рыбы"`
- Для `12:01 - 16:00` - `"Прием фруктов"`

Какую нужно прописать формулу в `B1`, чтобы при занесении в `A1` времени, допустим `9:47`, в `B1` стояла фраза `"Прием рыбы"`, соответственно с `12` до `16`, подставлялась `"Прием фруктов"`?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=ЕСЛИ(ЧАС(A1)<12;"Прием рыбы";"Прием фруктов")

Есть еще вариант сложнее но более гибкий

Создаем массив из двух колонок в первой часы во второй названия, после пием формулу =ИНДЕКС($E$1:$F$24;ЧАС(A1);2) *в моем случае и далее формула берет за значение строки час и колонка вторая [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это прекрасно подходит! Подскажите, а если взять больше диапазонов? Помимо уже известных, добавим 18: 00 - 23:00 и от 23:00 - 06:00. Спасибо!

Comment: Увеличивайте формулу если подуровнями. А если их совсем много то можно использовать суммесли

Comment: Добавил имитацию массива.

Comment: Нет диапазона от 0 до 1 часа. Но  для формулы это не проблема - ЧАС(A1)+1. Хуже, если в таблице пропуски часов (результат будет неверен). Правильнее *=ИНДЕКС($F$1:$F$24;ПОИСКПОЗ(ЧАС(A1);$E$1:$E$24))*

Comment: @vikttur Задача стояла найти вообще с 9:00 до 16:00. Но поиск по диапазону не решит вопрос с отсутствующим элементом. Можно добавить еще проверки, но зачем усложнять понимание человеку?  А так да поиск по диапазону может дать возможность найти даже не сортированные значения.

Comment: @ Ruslan Semenov, при отсутствии  элементов поиск по сортированному диапазону - неточное соответствие, как в показанном варианте с *ПОИСКПОЗ*

Answer (score 2):

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(A1>1/2;A1<=16/24);"Прием фрутов";ЕСЛИ(И(A1>=9/24;A1<=1/2);"Прием рыбы";"Нет приема")
```

Если условий (диапазонов) много, можно создать таблицу соответствий: первый столбец - начало диапазона, второй - соответствующий текст. Выбирать текст формулой:

```
=ВПР(A2;$C$2:$D$10;2)
```

где *A2* - время, *C2:D10* - таблица соответствий (в первой ячейке первого столбца - ноль)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При такой реализации границы можно задавать хоть с секундной точностью.

Еще один вариант: применение массива констант:

```
=ВПР(A2*24;{0;"ночь":6;"утро":7;"завтрак":10,5;"перерыв"};2)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш вариант тоже подходит.

Comment: Согласен с ВПР, тоже хороший вариант, +1